How can query Solr using a boolean query parser?
I'm trying to retrieve results from Solr using a boolean query parser. The query is simple now, but I'm planning on adding more queries to retrieve the intersection of the queries. The query I'm using looks like this :
?q={!type=bool+must=$dismaxQuery}&dismaxQuery={!type=dismax+qf=track_title&fl=score,+track_id&q.alt=*:*&start=0&rows=500}

So, the request would be :
http://localhost:8983/solr/track/select?q={!type=bool+must=$dismaxQuery}&dismaxQuery={!type=dismax+qf=track_title&fl=score,+track_id&q.alt=*:*&start=0&rows=500}

No matter what I do, I get a 200 OK with no results back. Surely I must be doing something wrong, but I don't get any errors and the Solr log doesn't complain about anything either.
Why is this query not working for me?

I would suggest running your query with debug=all and look at the debug on the Solr response. My guess is that the query is not being parsed properly and hopefully the debug response will give you some hints about the culprit.
